# how to organize team work with javascript in Adobe Acrobat forms

Tags: javascript, pdf, fdf, acrobat-sdk

I am newbie in Adobe Forms API.
Our team supports complicated Adobe Forms, doing events handlers, calculations etc.

For now i do not see way to sync our efforts via SVN, because of PDF binary nature. it looks impossible to merge changes made by different developers over one PDF file.

My idea is -  to have in SVN external js file not included in PDF and somehow evaluate in at document opening.

possible js code sources are

- evaluate pdf data attachment (js /txt)
- evaluate  remote data (soap, ADBC, ajax, cdn)

please give me a clue - what direction to follow.
am  i missing some simple idea how to get that?

I know about possibility to ask user to place JS file manually in APP folder but it is last resort.

[JS_Dev_Contexts documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_Dev_Contexts%2FJS_Dev_Contexts.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Here is our current solution]

Here is our current solution

- JS stored in git
- PDF is just a container of fields
- All actions are   set via JS